# Encoding special characters in xml

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

How to encode special characters in xml?
e.g: i have a special character mu in my xml, transformation will fail due to this character
any info would be helpful

Thanks
Preetham

Comment: Please tell us which special character you mean.

Comment: say i have this (Ω) in my xml how can i replace or encode it

Answer (score 11):

If you are building up your XML via string concatenation then you need to stop doing that and start using a library (e.g. DOM) in your language to create the XML.

The library will handle encoding correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Any valid UTF-8 character should be fine in XML, and any XML processing tool (including XSLT) should handle them also. If the file is valid XML, then it should work. Can you post an example XML file that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Should be fine, provided you specify no encoding or specify UTF-8!

Answer (score 0):

you can encode your xml in utf-8 and use

```
<node><![CDATA[ odd characters here ]]></node>
```

Comment: CDATA is only needed if you use characters with a special meaning (usually `&` and `<`). It has nothing to do with switching encoding or UTF-8!

Answer (score 0):

XML text defaults to the UTF-8 encoding. This supports all characters you care to throw at it. Only by deliberately selecting a non-international encoding would it fail to encode correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes referred to as "escaping", see [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx) for example.