# Escaping Characters in VB

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, ssis

I have a small script that loads in an XML from file and saves the data to a variable (the XML format is terrible and can't be changed!). Everything works fine, except the variable keeps dropping the backslashes ("\"). I have tried to run the Replace function to 'double up' the backslashes, see below:

```
Dim path As String
path = CType(Me.Dts.Variables("XMLINFilePath").Value, String)

Dim streamReader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
Dim StreamText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

StreamText = Replace(StreamText, "\", "\\")
Me.Dts.Variables("XMLContents").Value = StreamText
```

but the resulting variable still only has single backslashes. The replace function works as I can change other characters, it just seems to not detect any backslashes in the string, which there of course are! Is there a way that I can get the script to put the correct amount of backslashes in before saving it to a variable?

Thanks

Comment: try tripple backslashes, just might work

Comment: use '@' StreamText = Replace(StreamText, @"\", @"\\").  Triple won't work, need 4.

Comment: @JeremyC. No I tried that!

Comment: @jdweng That produces an error? I tried it with the @ symbol inside the quotes ("@\", "@\\"), but that didn't work either?

Comment: @jdweng - `@` is C# and not working in vb.net

Comment: give an example of the text that is causing the problem?

Comment: Here's a snippet: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"

Comment: Do you creating xml by your self?

Comment: No the XML is supplied, the format is horrible and can't be changed!

Comment: Normally I use the XML Task but the format is so convoluted that it doesn't work

Comment: Can you use [CDATA section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx) or [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)?

Comment: It says Xdocument is not defined? Do you have an example you can share?

Comment: You don't use backslash with XML. See webpage : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  Use CDATA like shown on webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272136/encoding-special-characters-in-xml

Comment: After you define StreamText, insert Dim newStreamText As String = StreamText.Replace("\","\\") and then use that new variable in place of StreamText for reassigning the value of XMLContents

Comment: this code is working for vb.net console application . I tried and I am able to see the changes in the xml.  try putting message box alert in your script after the replace statement and see what you are getting in  the streamtext string

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Main()



    Dim path As String
    path = "D:\Book.xml"

    Dim streamReader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim StreamText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    StreamText = Replace(StreamText, "\", "\\")
    MsgBox(StreamText)

    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

see this image what I have posted for the change :http://i58.tinypic.com/mky7uu.jpg

and make sure your xml is correct. add 
this code :